# Mysterious ghost margins -- is minipage to blame?

Tags: margins, minipage

I'm trying to create a basic template for an A4 paper document. As always when I try to do any sort of precision in Latex, there seem to be annoying random margins popping up.

A4 paper is exactly 297mm high and 210mm wide. I'm using the fullpage package with `[cm]`, hence I should have a remaining usable height of 277mm and width of 190mm. However, if I create one or several minipages (above each other) I'd expect their cumulative height to have 277mm available and their cumulative width (on each row) 190mm. However, a `\begin{minipage}[c][277mm][c]{190mm}` causes Latex to emit a warning that

- the `\hbox` is 28.45273pt too wide (this is precisely 1cm) and
- the `\vbox` is 53.45273pt too high (1.89cm)

and distributing that width/height among several minipages causes newlines and newpages.

How can I get rid of all these margins, to allow a precise template down to the mm. I will later add appropriate margins, but I want to be able to control them.

Perhaps there is a better documentclass for (fairly naked) one-page documents? I think beamerposter would be overkill for what I want to do.

---

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[cm]{fullpage}
\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\pagestyle{empty}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[c][277mm][c]{190mm}
\it Lorem ipsum
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Side note: Never use the long outdated `ngerman` package but rather `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `minipage` is bigger than text area of your document. To see this add `showframe` package and `\fbox` around ``minipage`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[cm]{fullpage}
\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\pagestyle{empty}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}

\fbox{\begin{minipage}[c][277mm]{190mm}
\it Lorem ipsum
\end{minipage}%
    }
\end{document}
```

lower part of page is:

[image]

(red lines shows page layout, black ones border of `minipage` drawn by `\fbox{...}`)

Since `minipage` is bigger than text area, it is pushed to the next page.

Why you like to have such big page, is unclear. However this warning you can remove with following size of `minipae`You can reduce/remove t

```
\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}
\addtolength\fboxsep{-2\fboxrule}
\fbox{\begin{minipage}[c][\textheight]{\textwidth}
\it Lorem ipsum
\end{minipage}%
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that `fullpage[1cm]` doesn't do it's job as expected. It works correctly when setting the margin with the -- apparently -- more precise `geometry` package:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{units}
\usepackage{calc}

\pagestyle{empty}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
% these are not strictly necessary
\setlength{\footskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{0pt}
```